# Duplicate local variable in switch statement

Tags: java, eclipse, switch-statement

I was getting this error using Eclipse.

> Duplicate local variable cape

I really don't understand why I was getting such an error. This was my code:

```
switch (frame) {  // frame is an integer
case 0:
    Sprite cape = modules.get(Module.CAPE);
    //cape.setRegion(region);
    cape.translateY(+1);
    break;
case 1:
    Sprite cape = modules.get(Module.CAPE);
    //cape.setRegion(region);
    cape.translateY(-1);
    break;
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Undefined frame number: " + frame);
}
```

Why is it not true that the cape variable is local to each case, but instead to the switch statement?

Comment: Good answers have already been provided but to strictly answer your question, consider how the code would behave if you removed the `break` in case 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is it not true that the cape variable is local to each case, but
>   instead to the switch statement?

Because the [JLS says so](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a **block** (§14.4) is the
>   rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its
>   own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in
>   the local variable declaration statement.

And about [`switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)

> The body of a switch statement is known as a **switch block**.

A `case` does not define a scope. It's the `switch` block that defines a new scope.

Answer (score 20):

The whole `switch` statement is a code block like any other. But you can create code blocks inside code blocks, so:

```
case 0: {
    // code here
}
case 1: {
    // other code here
}
```

(if the `switch` were treated specially in this regard you couldn't be able to do follow through)

Comment: +1 Curly braces define scope. case labels are like a goto.

Answer (score 9):

Each case is within the same block, specifically, the `{}` for the `switch` statement.  This is the same block even when different cases define the same variable.

Define your own blocks for each case by adding `{}`s:

```
case 0:
  {
    Sprite cape = modules.get(Module.CAPE);
    //cape.setRegion(region);
    cape.translateY(+1);
  }
    break;
case 1:
  {
    Sprite cape = modules.get(Module.CAPE);
    //cape.setRegion(region);
    cape.translateY(-1);
  }
    break;
```

Or you can simply declare `cape` before the `switch` so it's in scope there, where you use the reference.

```
Sprite cape;
switch (frame) {  // frame is an integer
case 0:
    cape = modules.get(Module.CAPE);
```

and similarly for case 1.

Comment: Alternately you could define 'Sprite cape' outside of the switch, and then set it in each case.

Comment: @Scott Yes, I was getting to that!

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `cape` variable outside `switch` statement:

```
Sprite cape;
switch (frame) {
    case 0:
        cape = modules.get(Module.CAPE);
        //cape.setRegion(region);
        cape.translateY(+1);
        break;
    case 1:
        cape = modules.get(Module.CAPE);
        //cape.setRegion(region);
        cape.translateY(-1);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Undefined frame number: " + frame);
}
```

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: @Someone because everything inside switch belong to the same scope

Comment: @Someone: It does, you just don't realize it

Comment: @GIJoe **Why** is it not true that the cape variable is local to each case, but instead to the switch statement?  I'm not asking how I can stop getting the error.

Comment: @Someone: Because the case statements are labels. The compiler defines scope as what is between the switch block (aka the curly braces). The object can't be defined twice in the same block with the same name. It would be the same problem if you had defined it on two different lines in a function.